# Git Sparse Checkout Leaves No Entry on Working Directory

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to use sparse-checkout to just check-out a directory from a BitBucket repository, but getting a "Sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory" error when I try to pull.

The BitBucket repository has the following directory structure:

- SomeProjectRepo

  - JohnsProject
  - MarysProject
  - MyProject

I have a local directory on E:\Temp\SomeProjectRepo on my Windows 7 laptop. I want to just checkout/pull "MyProject" from the BitBucket repository to my local directory, so I can just work on E:\Temp\SomeProjectRepo\MyProject.

So I created "E:\Temp\SomeProjectRepo" and did the following in DOS:

1. `cd E:\Temp\SomeProjectRepo`
2. `git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/blah/blah`
3. `git init`
4. `git config core.sparsecheckout true`
5. `echo MyProject > .git/info/sparse-checkout`
6. `git pull origin master`

At step 6, I get the "Sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory". I have tried different syntax in step 5 (e.g. `MyProject\`, `SomeProjectRepo\*`, `SomeProjectRepo\MyProject\`, etc, etc) but none worked.

How do I use sparse-checkout (or any other tools) to only work on "`MyProject`"?

Comment: I think you should do step 3 and then step 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Windows git: “error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on the working directory”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289006/on-windows-git-error-sparse-checkout-leaves-no-entry-on-the-working-directory)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

OK, I got this working. As I expected it was not working because of step 5.

The line below works now:

```
echo "MyProject/*"> .git/info/sparse-checkout
```

The important thing is to use `/`, use `*` and leave no space at the end of the directory.

Then you may pull again or checkout the branch (`git checkout master`).

Comment: This also solved my problem with Jenkins sparse checkouts. The checkout path in the Jenkins SCM must use forward slashes. http://i.stack.imgur.com/VD93V.png

Comment: thanks you made my day! :) actually you dont need to echo the fullpath to the subdirectory .  you should echo the location excluding the repo url ! lol

Comment: Note for windows users: do not use powershell for the echo command. Use git bash instead. See duplicate answser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289006/on-windows-git-error-sparse-checkout-leaves-no-entry-on-the-working-directory/23289007

Comment: The * was the missing puzzle tile that did the trick for me after many times trying

Answer (score 6):

### Solution for Windows users

On **Windows**, the `echo "..." > outfile` command creates a file in default system encoding. Git cannot deal with that, it requires the file to be in **ASCII**.

#### Powershell

Modify the existing file to become ASCII, assuming you created it already and it doesn't work:

```
Set-Content .git\info\sparse-checkout "MyProject/*" -Encoding Ascii
```

Or to create the file with correct encoding from the start:

```
echo MyProject/* | out-file -Encoding Ascii .git/info/sparse-checkout
```

#### Background

See the longer explanation here [On Windows git: “error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on the working directory”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289006/on-windows-git-error-sparse-checkout-leaves-no-entry-on-the-working-directory/)

Answer (score 3):

if you are working on windows the same as me

> you shouldn't get the quotes in the sparse-checkout file, and it will not work
>   and
>   need to use /* at the end of the path

this works for me

> echo src/* >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

Answer (score 2):

**Windows Git 2.25 Note**

2.25 includes the `git sparse-checkout` feature to frontend some of this work. However, as far as i can tell it writes to the sparse-checkout file as UTF8, which is the same problem noted by Willem

I used the powershell solution in this thread to force ascii
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55158885/12927399

Just providing a gotcha warning for `git sparse-checkout` command!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the specific folder I was trying to pull didn't yet exist in the repository. So I had to do a push that included the folder (**'dist'** folder from a built NuxtJS project), then the error was gone and sparse-checkout worked as expected.