# How to pull and push sub directory in Git

Tags: git, git-push, git-checkout, sparse-checkout

My requirement is to pull and push files only for particular folder from the master repo. The method I am using is only helping me in pulling files for particular folder but not in pushing.

So in my master repo I have folder structure something like below.

```
mainfolder
  examfold1
  examfold2
  examfold3
```

this is what i am doing.

```
git clone http://123456@onestash-test.com/mainfolder
cd mainfolder
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo examfold3/*> .git/info/sparse-checkout
```

this is working fine when i pull, it doesn't bring files on other folders  but it also not bringing files for examfold3 and i get below error when i push after making some files changes from local repo.

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://123456@onestash-test.com/mainfolder'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I believe git is thinking my local repo is not sync with master because i didn't pull files for other folder. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `git status` show? AFAIK a sparse checkout does not affect pulls/pushes, it just affects which files are checked out into your working directory.

Comment: On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: And after you do a `git pull`, is the `git status` the same?

Comment: * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 71dd862..04ce809
error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory

Comment: Hmm... does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289006/on-windows-git-error-sparse-checkout-leaves-no-entry-on-the-working-directory help?