# How to get a specific folder in develop branch git repository (VSTS) to my local directory

Tags: git, github, repository, azure-devops, git-clone

I have a repository https://phm-dsc.visualstudio.com/PHM/_git/repo in VSTS git. How do I get a folder within this repository to my local using powershell/batch script commands? I tried the following but did not work (getting this error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on the working directory). any suggestions will help

```
 mkdir sql
cd sql
git init
git remote add origin -f <<https URL of repository>>
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo <<path of the folder>> >>.git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work - or at least you are close. I have a script that does essentially the same thing and those steps look basically right.

However, try removing the `-f` option from `git remote add origin`.  You don't really want the fetch to happen until the `sparse-checkout` file is created.  That may be the issue.

If you still aren't able to get it to work, why don't you consider posting the steps you're trying along with a public repo (either on VSTS or github).  That way others can try the steps to see what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can read some tips in "[On Windows git: “error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on the working directory”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23289007/6309)"

In particular:

> - The `<path you want to checkout>` might look like this: `path/to/subfolder` - note the lack of leading and trailing path separators.
> - Important: Be sure to use a git bash prompt for the below, and use an editor supporting unix line-ending conventions and save as ANSI when editing the sparse-checkout file, or you may get “error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on the working directory” errors.

So double-check the eol (end of line) used in your `.git/info/sparse-checkout` file.

Answer (score 0):

To get a folder from VSTS git repo to your local directory, you can follow below commands (assume the folder name is `myfolder`, and it located in `master` branch):

```
mkdir sql
cd sql
git init
git remote add origin -f https://phm-dsc.visualstudio.com/PHM/_git/repo
cd repo
git checkout origin/master myfolder/
```

Now the contents in `myfolder` is get, you can commit to your local git repo if necessary.

Comment: THanks.cd repo will not work in this case. i get 'The system cannot find the path specified' error

Comment: Please check if the folder with the name `sql` exist. Or you can execute the commands start from `git init` (skip the first two commands)  in my answer in an empty folder directly.